# WPF hide Grid Row with an Expander

Tags: wpf, animation, grid, expander

In my app it has a Grid Row with only an expander in it.  What I want is for this Grid/Expander to be shown when the expander is expanded but hidden when not.  I figured putting the height of the expander to 0 and the height of the Grid.Row to Auto would fix this.  Problem is that when this is done the expander no longer expands.

Thanks for the help

Edit:  Thanks to @Blam he solved the problem with this;

```
<Expander.Style>
<Style TargetType="Expander">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</Expander.Style>
```

Although did cause another minor issue to occur.  I had an animation on the expander, when expanding the animation shows.  Although on collapsing the animation does not.  I am assuming the visibility property is effect instantly therefore no time is given for the animation.

Is there a way to put a delay in this property?

Comment: Set the Expandar Visibility to Collapsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Expander Visibility to Collapsed

I would try putting the Visibility in the Expander Collapsed event

Comment: Sorry maybe I am just slow, but how does that fix animation issue?

Comment: Since I don't know how you have the animation set up I don't know for sure.  I just said that is what I would try.   I think this is a new question.